# Facebook feed page post id is encrypted. How to decrypt?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am calling feeds.php to get the page feeds.

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=102555409843504

But, getting the "id" field as encrypted-

```
 "title": "This is a test feed.",
 "id": "47cbba059e97f5c688870473dc30ec5a",
 "alternate": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/permalink.php?story_fbid=373792589386450&id=102555409843504",
```

Although, the "alternate" key has the post-id written in a clean way. Then why is the id encrypted?
 Wanted to call  Graph API with each post-Id. Is there a simple way to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you getting the feed with the Graph API?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/102555409843504/feed
```

Comment: graph call requires an access token. Am getting error in the call.